# u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!' in OpenERP V7

Tags: xml, openerp-7

In my module i try to regtoup the date field by day, but when trying to upgrade the module an Invalid XML for view error appear:

This is the part of XML that generate the error (:year):

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="id_view_contact">
            <field name="name">test.base.graph.view1</field>
            <field name="model">test.base</field>
            <field name="type">graph</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <graph string="contacts" type="bar"  >
                    <field name="create_date:year" type="row" group="False" />
                    <field name="name" type="col"/>
                </graph>                        
            </field>
        </record>
```

this is the OpenERP V7 documentation that shows the datetime attribute: [OpenERP V7 Documentation](https://doc.odoo.com/trunk/web_graph/)

Thanks in advance.

This is the exact error:

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\http.py", line 204, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1137, in call_button
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 1125, in _call_kw
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 42, in proxy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 103, in send


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\web\session.py", line 89, in send
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\netsvc.py", line 300, in dispatch_rpc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\service\web_services.py", line 628, in dispatch
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\service\security.py", line 40, in check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 49, in get_pool
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 203, in get
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\registry.py", line 233, in new
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 351, in load_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 187, in load_module_graph
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 74, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\modules\loading.py", line 124, in _load_data
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 959, in convert_xml_import
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 852, in parse
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\tools\convert.py", line 819, in _tag_record
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_model.py", line 956, in _update
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\openerp\addons\base\ir\ir_ui_view.py", line 214, in write
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 4325, in write
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenERP 7.0-20150506\server\.\openerp\osv\orm.py", line 1577, in _validate
except_orm: ('ValidateError', u'Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!')
```

Comment: can u paste the exact error log. it might helpful to find the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your syntax :

```
 <field name="create_date:year" type="row" group="False" />
```

":year" doesn't exist in OpenERP v7, it is a new feature that was added in Odoo 8, the new version of OpenERP.